# Javascript timer stopping at 1, not continuing to 0

Tags: javascript, html, timer, countdown

I've been trying to get this javascript countdown working and have gotten it to countdown from 3 to 1, however I can't figure out why it doesnt go all the way down to 0?

**Why does it stop at 1 and how do I make it count down fully?**

```
<body>
<p>Time left: <span id="time">3</span> seconds.</p>
<p><a href="#" onclick="play()">Play</a> <a href="#" onclick="pause()">Pause</a></p>
<script>
var time = 3,
timeElement = document.getElementById('time'),
timer = null;
var updateTimer = function() {
  timeElement.innerHTML = time--;
  if (time === 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
}
function play() {
    timer = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
    return false;
}
function pause() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    return false;
}
</script>
</body>
```

You can also test the JsFiddle I made here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vg4kQ/
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use prefix instead of postfix decrement:

```
timeElement.innerHTML = --time;
```

---

This has to do with the semantic differences between the prefix and postfix increment/decrement operators. They both increment/decrement the value of the variable, as expected, but they do not evaluate to the same value when used as expressions.

Prefix increment/decrement both function the way most people would expect: they adjust the variable's value, then evaluate to the new value.

```
var x = 5;
console.log(++x); // 6
console.log(x);   // 6
```

Postfix operators are a little less intuitive. They still modify the value the same way, but when used as expressions, they evaluate to the variable's value *before* it was modified.

```
var x = 5;
console.log(x++); // 5
console.log(x);   // 6
```

In your code, when `time` reached 0, the postfix expression still yielded the previous value, 1, making `timeElement`'s value still display 1, but still ending the loop. Converting the expression to use prefix decrement fixes that problem.

Alternatively, you could always just split it up into two statements.

```
time--;
timeElement.innerHTML = time;
```

Comment: time = 3, decrements to 2, outputs 2. time = 2, decrements to 1, outputs 1. time = 1, decrements to 0, outputs 0, finishes